# How call this function 10 times

Tags: javascript, function, repeat

I was working on something where a duck disappears every time he is clicked and re appears 1 second later. But i want to make him reappear only 10 times and then stop after that. So what is a simple approach to make it appear only 10 times? I have tried using loops, but i was not able to do it properly.

[image]

Comment: put a counter on the function

Comment: please add your code as text - not as an image

Comment: If you could, please edit  *your actual code* as text into your question - images of code *alone* are [tedious and difficult](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) to work with and debug. It forces those who would otherwise love to help you to [transcribe your image](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) first, which is a waste of time.

Comment: Just to clarify, after the 10th time, does the element stop disappearing, or after the 10th time, does the element disappear and never reappears?

Comment: Please don't upload [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3082296). They can't be copied to reproduce the issue, aren't searchable for future readers and harder to read than text. Please post the actual code as text to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a **counter** like below. You just have to edit my code a bit to suit your purposes.

```js
var counter = 0;

$(".button").click(function() {
  if (counter < 10) {
    $(".text").hide();
    counter++;
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".text").show();
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button">Click</button>
<p class="text">Text</p>
```

Comment: OP wants to call `reAppear` on click of something. Not after an interval

Comment: @adiga Right fixed it.

Comment: Thanks it works :). I can finally continue with my project. my code looks like this https://pastebin.com/wckHDv2u

Comment: @CharlesSudip your welcome. Accept the answer to let others know it worked for you as well